# W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Tags: apt, updates

i am new to Ubuntu and have probably done something stupid.

trying to update, and gets an annoying error.

```
Reading package lists... Done                


W: Failed to fetch http://archive-canonical.com/dists/&(lsb_release-sc)/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive-canonical.com/dists/&(lsb_release-sc)/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive-canonical.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

after reading abit online, it seems that there something wrong here:
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

so here are the results:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.telianet.dk/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive-canonical.com/ &(lsb_release-sc) partner
# deb-src http://archive-canonical.com/ &(lsb_release-sc) partner
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

help please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, the line should look like:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

It doesn't work or the formatting is wrong for the `$(lsb_release -sc)` part.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No. <br/>

here is what the last 6 lines look like now: 
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu &(lsb_release -sc) partner
# deb-src http://archive-canonical.com/ &(lsb_release-sc) partner
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

Comment: @Jman Change all the `$(lsb_release -sc)` parts to `trusty`.  The `$(lsb_release -sc)` is actually part of a command that can be used in an `echo` statement to add the proper name to the file.  A test would show that if you type in `echo $(lsb_release -sc)` from a terminal window, it should say `trusty` which is the Ubuntu release name.

Comment: sorry, i am just easily confused.
i just did something wrong. everything is ok now. 
Thanks :)

Comment: @Jman You are very welcome!  =)

Comment: Also fixed my Rythmbox issue :)
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the sources list file in `/etc/apt/`

```
mv sources.list
```

Go to https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php and create a new sources list file:

```
nano sources.list
```

Save and test.

Comment: `mv sources.list` lacks argument

Comment: Also you should use absolute paths, or point out explicitly that the user must be in `/etc/apt` (so either the latter or `mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak` and `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`).